# проблема с f строкой python

Tags: python, f-strings

```
name = 'Nicholas'
balance = '3200$'
mid_name = 'Price'

text = f""""Уважаемый, {name} {mid_name}, баланс вашего лицевого счёта составляет: {balance}"""
```

```
строка:1 знак:9
+ sadfdsfs& C:/Users/Nikita/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/pyt ...
+        ~
Амперсанд (&) не разрешен. Оператор & зарезервирован для будущих версий. Добавьте двойные кавычки до и после амперсанда ("&"), чтобы передать его как строку.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

Comment: Но в коде нет амперсанда.

Comment: Ещё непонятно, зачем столько кавычек )

Comment: мало того, что кавычек избыточное количество, так еще и не равное

Answer (score 1):

```
f"Уважаемый, {name} {mid_name}, баланс вашего лицевого счёта составляет: {balance}"
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Тройные кавычки используются для многострочной записи:

```
print("""
Usage: thingy [OPTIONS]
     -h                        Display this usage message
     -H hostname               Hostname to connect to
""")
```

Проверь количество кавычек слева и вправо. Все должно работать